# URL redirection using .htaccess, but multiple domain at a time

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Is there any possible .htaccess method to re-direct all the mentioned pages to www.example.com  only

http://www.example.com/?cPath=3&cPath=3&products_id=spade/3

http://www.example.com/?cPath=30&cPath=30&products_id=sale/30

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/\?cPath=30?&cPath=30?&products_id=spade/30? [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thank Mr.Anubhava, I tried this code, unfortunately this is not working

Comment: This works fine in my tests. Are there more rules? Make sure this is very first rule and it is in root .htaccess

Comment: yes , actually we have three domains all hosted in the same ftp, for eg ftp.example.com and 3 domains such as example1.com, example2.com apart from example.com; whn i used the same url redirect code to the root of example.com, it directly affect other domains also and not only that there is no exact result i am getting...thanks Jk